# How to format Table of contents automatically in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

I know I can create Table of contents (TOC) based on the Header titles in the body of the page. This is great as every time I add a new header, I just click on the refresh button on the TOC and the new header is added. However sometimes my TOC is 2-3 pages long and I would like to have more control over its formatting.

How can I add extra space on top and below some titles in the TOC, but also without losing that formatting option every time I refresh the TOC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shift+Enter in the Headlines to make spaces in the TOC.
Though: just blank Shift+Enter line will not work - you need to enter any character in the extra line, and that character should not be a space.

You can use a dot or a, for example, that will show up in the TOC, ad not take a lot of attention..

I notice that the "hard-space" created on Windows by alt+numeric 255 do shoow up as a "-", so the extra line cannot be completely blank with that character.
Maybe other of the specal characters are interesting ;-)